# ngrx: How to call a reducer before and after an effect

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to fix the following warning:`ESLint: Calling 'store.dispatch' in 'Effect' is forbidden.`

The effect in question does generally this:

- lock data in the store using a reducer
- update the backend data
- unlock the data

Code:

```
    this.actions$.pipe(
              ofType(actions.update),
              switchMap(action => {
                this.store.dispatch(actions.lockData(action.data.id));
                return this.backendService.update$(action.data)
                 .pipe(
                    map(...),
                    catchError(...),
                    finalize(()=> this.store.dispatch(actions.unlockData(action.data.id))  
                    )
```

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock/unlock the data with the action that triggers the effect, and with the action that is returned from the effect.

In your case this means `actions.update`, and the action returned in the `map` method.